# Visual Basic - Progress Bar resetar automaticamente

Tags: vb.net

Boa Noite!

Eu estou fazendo um programa em Visual Basic, e preciso que minha Progress Bar volte ao 0 automaticamente quando chegar em 100, e meu timer pare quando o Value da Progress Bar chegue a 100.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

#### Código do Programa

```
Public Class DevKit
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Dinheiro.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Experiencia.Click

End Sub

Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RPGMakerBar.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RPGMaker.Click
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    RPGMakerBar.Increment(1)
    If RPGMakerBar.Value = 100 Then
        QtdDinheiro.Text = QtdDinheiro.Text
    End If
    PctRPGMaker.Text = RPGMakerBar.Value & (" %")

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PctRPGMaker.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Acrescente o seguinte código dentro da função

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    RPGMakerBar.Increment(1)
    If RPGMakerBar.Value = 100 Then
        QtdDinheiro.Text = QtdDinheiro.Text
        Timer1.Stop()
        RPGMakerBar.Value = 0
    End If
    PctRPGMaker.Text = RPGMakerBar.Value & (" %")

End Sub
```